# How to get the current time of OS in Haskell

Tags: haskell

In Erlang, for instance, I can do this:

```
:os.system_time
===> 
1583672603234876000
```

In Haskell I haven't found a way to do that. How can I do it? **Without a third-party dependency !!!**

I tried:

```
import System.Time (getClockTime)


tm <- getClockTime
```

but an error was:

```
Could not find module ‘System.Time’
```

which implied that I found an old example.

Comment: You need to install the module, for example with `cabal`: `cabal intall old-time`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem re-read my question

Comment: well it is based on a foreign c call: https://github.com/joeyadams/haskell-system-time-monotonic/blob/master/System/Time/Monotonic/Direct.hsc#L194

Comment: What's wrong with a dependency exactly?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin why do you need to know that?

Comment: @Jarru Your future use of Haskell is going to be hampered greatly if you restrict yourself to libraries that ship with GHC itself.

Comment: Importing stuff from libraries is completely normal in Haskell. In fact, even the "base" stuff that you'd consider "standard" does come from a library called "base". So complaining that a certain thing that you'd like to use is a "third-party dependency" seems strange and meaningless. Unless you have a specific reason to avoid libraries except "base". Which is why I asked.

Answer (score 5):

If you wish something akin to Erlang's `os:system_time()`, you may try `time`'s [getSystemTime](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.9.3/docs/Data-Time-Clock-System.html#v:getSystemTime).

---

> In Haskell I haven't found a way to do that. How can I do it? Without a third-party dependency !!!

Albeit a dependency, `time` is far from being third-party.
According to its [source repository](https://github.com/haskell/time)'s README:

> This is the haskell time library that is bundled with GHC the Glasgow/ Glorious Haskell compiler.

---

Moreover, `time` provides some more functions to get various representations of the current time, such as [getCurrentTime](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.9.3/docs/Data-Time-Clock.html#v:getCurrentTime).

Hope you find all of this useful!

Cheers.

Comment: does `getCurrentTime` return OS system time, in the same format as `:os.system_time`?

Comment: Why don't you read its documentation or try it yourself?